# NSArray and NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, instance

The book I'm currently reading has me write the following code :

```
-(IBAction)displaySomeText:(id)sender {
    NSString *cow = @"Milk";
    NSString *chicken = @"Egg";
    NSString *goat = @"Butter";

    NSArray *food = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cow, chicken, goat, nil];

    NSString *string = @"The shopping list is: ";
    string = [string stringByAppendingString:[food componentsJoinedByString:@", "]];

    [textView insertText:string];
```

}

I understand somewhat how arrays work but I need help understanding the following code

```
string = [string stringByAppendingString:[food componentsJoinedByString:@", "]];
```

I have never ever seen an instance where this is possible.

He has me create a 'string' object, from the `NSString` class, and then I'm doing this

```
string = [string stringByAppendingString:];
```

I'm confused. I have never seen an example where I create an object and then perform a method on the same object and store it in that exact same object.

For example, I know I can do this

```
NSSound *chirp;
chirp = [NSSound soundNamed:@"birdChirp.mp3"];
```

the above makes sense because I used the created object and performed a class method on it..

but I always assumed that the equivalent of the following code  was  NOT possible

```
chirp = [chirp methodNameEtc..];
```

I hope I explained my question well. If not I could always elaborate further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the heart of your question *"I'm confused. I have never seen an example where I create an object and then perform a method on the same object and store it in that exact same object."*

To answer that question, your not actually '*storing it in the exact same object*'. What you are doing is confusing `pointers` and `objects`.

Let's just look at this line:

`string = [string stringByAppendingString:@"Hello"];`

In this line 'string' is a `pointer`, not the `object` it points to. What this line of code is saying is: 
"`Object` currently referenced by the `pointer` 'string', return to me a new `NSString` `object` whose text is your text with this text added. And when I get that new `NSString` `object` I ordered make the `pointer` 'string' point to that `object` instead."

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is the best answer so far. I'm glad you saw through all that, lol. 

Thank's so much.

Comment: This question might sound dumb but I don't program much in ObjC: Since Strings are immutable, wouldn't this cause a memory leak since the original string object now has no pointer to it (since the stringByAppendingString returns a new string object)?

Comment: Yes. The old string has been dereferenced as you say. This is okay if the dereferenced object is autoreleased or a string literal created like `NSString *cow = @"Milk"` but if it was a retained string that would be a memory leak. Interestingly most memory leak questions on this site seem to be people confusing pointers and objects.

Comment: OP here again. 

Is it safe to say that 

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"];

is to Class method's as 

NSString *string = [string stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@"];

is to instance method's?

Because it just seems like the first one performs a Class method and stores value in the pointer and the second one performs a instance method and stores value in the pointer. 

Am I correct here?

Comment: Yes, everything after "Because" is correct. But neither of those code examples will do anything useful (In fact the first will crash). But the gist of your point is correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
string = [string stringByAppendingString:[food componentsJoinedByString:@", "]];
```

is the same as

```
NSString *tmpString = [food componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
string = [string stringByAppendingString:tmpString];
```

So in the example, the innermost square brackets are evaluated first, and then the outermost. Does that clarify it a bit? Thing of it like parentheses in math: (1*2*(1+2))... the innermost () get evaluated before you can determine that the real problem is 1*2*3. That is what is happening with `[food componentsJoinedByString:@", "]`.

Answer (score 1):

`stringByAppendingString` is not storing the string in the exact same object.  It's one `NSString` object creating a new (autoreleased) `NSString` object.

There is no equivalent example for `chirp` (which is a `NSSound` object), unless you create your own category which extends `NSSound` with a method to return a brand new `NSSound` object.

Makes sense?

Oh, I also appreciate your Takizawa icon.

Comment: Thank's a lot to all who answered. I get it now.