# How to store variables in array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, variables, nsarray

How can we store variables inside an array in xcode?

I have something like this:

array = @[@1,@2,@3];

I need something like this:

array = @[_a,_b,_c];

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What are the data types of `_a`, `_b`, and `_c`?

Comment: May I know the reason for down vote please?

Comment: Most likely down voted because of a lack of detail. Also, this question has been duplicated many times. You can get down voted for duplicating.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you store "int" values in an NSMutableArray\* or NSMutableDictionary\*? Chronic problems with JSON data that come in as integers.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764391/how-do-you-store-int-values-in-an-nsmutablearray-or-nsmutabledictionary-chr)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making an array of integers in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340153/making-an-array-of-integers-in-objective-c)

Comment: But I dont think this was my issue and moreover the solutions are different. My issue is resolved using the below answer. Please let me know how this down votes can be resolved

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSArray and NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364898/nsarray-and-nsstring)

Comment: This was my solution: _Result = @[@((inputvalue -1) * 1), @(inputvalue), @(((inputvalue -2) * 2)+3)];

Comment: I don't think it is related to any of the possible duplicates. I don't find justification for the down votes. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done like this:

```
array = @[@(_a), @(_b), @(_c)];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I have a small doubt. How to include calculations inside array? Ex: @[@((_a * 1) + 1),@(_b),@(_c)];